# IntelliJ reports package does not exist (only on Windows)

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, guava

I am pretty new to the whole Java eco-system and I am already spending hours to get an external dependency to work with IntelliJ. I use a simple Java application that contains an `App.java` containing:

```
package com.example.maven;

import com.google.common.collect.ImmutableList;

public class App
{
    public static void main( String[] args )
    {
        ImmutableList<String> list = ImmutableList.of("hello", "world");
        for (String item : list) {
            System.out.println( item );
        }
    }
}
```

The `pom.xml` contains a dependency to com.google.guava (required for `ImmutableList`) that looks like this:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
  <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
  <version>30.1-jre</version>
</dependency>
```

Whenever I try to debug, I get the error that `com.google.common.collect.ImmutableList` cannot be loaded.  I also tried to clone https://github.com/tfnico/guava-example (updated Java version to a supported version), but no luck.

It seems to be an issue with my Windows PC. My Mac doesn't have any issues, but I have removed everything from my Windows PC (Java JRE, SDKs, IntelliJ and reinstalled it again). I don't want to develop on my Mac. Why doesn't this work on Windows???

Comment: you could just create a gradle project (in IntelliJ) and add the dependencies using implementation

Comment: @IntoVoid I don't want to use Gradle, because everything else is in Maven. But I just found out it's only a problem on my Windows box :-(

Answer (score 1):

Can you share your whole pom.xml and explain what exactly you mean by "debugging"? The IntelliJ Debugger?
I tried to reproduce your error but it didn't worked. I can run the program without any errors, in "normal" run mode and in debug mode.
Did you correctly imported the dependency like this?

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
        <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
        <version>30.1-jre</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Did you reload the Maven project so it really downloaded the dependency? [See how to reload](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1n5sF.png)

Comment: This is more a comment than an answer.

Comment: I have pushed an example to https://github.com/ramondeklein/maventest that contains the complete `pom.xml`. The second commit also contains all the IDEA files. I try to use 'Run' - 'Debug...' and then it shows 'java: package com.google.common.collect does not exist'. It's weird I cannot find a simple example with IntelliJ and Maven that uses an external module. Without external module it works fine...

Comment: FYI: I also tried this example and got "package org.apache.logging.log4j does not exist". Could it be an issue with my Windows installation?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem this morning and I fixed it by doing the following steps:

1. Close Intellij
2. remove folder [HOME]/.m2/repository
3. remove folder [MY_PROJECT]/.idea/libraries
4. Open Intellij
5. mvn dependency:resolve
6. mvn install

I think doing only 6 (without 5) may work the same

Answer (score 0):

Check to see if the dependency (package) that could not be found is annotated as being required only for `runtime`. This is clearly not true if it is refered to in an `import` statement in which case it is also required for `compile`.

If this is the case, then

- For maven : remove `<scope>runtime</scope>` below the dependency declaration
- For gradle : change `runtime` in front of the dependency declaration to `compile` or `implementation`.

Answer (score -1):

I guess something was wrong with my IntelliJ settings. I did the following steps and then it worked:

1. Remove all Java installations on my system.
2. Remove IntelliJ
3. Remove all JDKs and files in /.m2.
4. Remove all .idea folders, .iml files and target folders.
5. Reinstalled IntelliJ
6. Reinstalled Zulu 15 JDK
7. Run File - Manage IDE Settings - Restore default settings
8. Load the project

Then debugging works. Don't know why...